# How can I solve this problem in my WordPress site Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_rs_plugin_url()

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am trying to install Slider Revolution, but it shows the error below. Please help me resolve this issue!

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_rs_plugin_url() (previously declared
> in
> /home/growbigr/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider.php:263)
> in
> /home/growbigr/public_html/wp-content/plugins/slider-revolution/revslider.php
> on line 264

[image]

Comment: The error is quite self-explanatory: You are using `revslider` plugin that probably already declares that function. So you have to use either of the two

Comment: if the function is your code, you can add a guard like this `if (!function_exists('get_rs_plugin_url')) { /* here your function declaration */ }` which avoids double declaration

Answer (score 0):

yes indeed, it is like the two others wrote. If you did not created a function like this, probably the theme author did. You can test this by changing the theme temporarily. If you need more help please contact either the theme author's support or ours (depending on whose customer you are).

Cheers, Dirk @ Slider Revolution